# Creating Action Hooks For Automatic File Inclusion

Tags: customization, hooks, include

I want to create a hook for automatic file inclusion in my plugin, but I am finding my stuck moments. May be somebody could help me out. Here is what I tried:

```
$args = array(
        "url" =>""
);
do_action_ref_array("file_register", $args);


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function register_mytest() {
// php file name is here!
}

add_action("file_register", "register_mytest");
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the file usage. If you want to include file automatically everythime plugin loads, why dont you simply put `include` or `require_once` at the top of plugin `index`-file?

Comment: I want to create extendable plugin and don't want to open and write in the related file everytime creating a new php file and also to prevent other developer from having more works and confusions by doing so. May be there is a better suggestion.